# How to Find Inverse Fourier Transform of Specific Function

Tags: inverse, fourier-transform

I have the function

$$
F(\omega)=\frac{\cos \left(a \sqrt{\omega }\right)+\cosh \left(a \sqrt{\omega }\right)}{\cos \left(\sqrt{\omega }\right) \cosh \left(\sqrt{\omega }\right)-1}
\,.
$$

where a is a constant value $$0<a<1$$ It should be noted that the function is even, namely,$$F(\omega )=F(-\omega )$$  How can I find the analytical form of inverse Fourier transform?

Comment: The (inverse) Fourier transform only takes functions that are defined on the whole real line.

Comment: The function is even, namely,$$ f(\omega )=f(-\omega )$$

Comment: @YuriyS The function is even without the absolute value since $\cosh(ix) = \cos(x)$ and vice versa

Comment: @NinadMunshi, you are right, my mistake

Comment: I guess residue theory should help with the integral, at least turn it into a series

Comment: If $|a|\ge 1$, the function does not tend to zero as $\omega\to\infty$.

Comment: What convention are you using for Fourier transform (the exponent sign and the scaling factor)?

Comment: The convention is $F(\omega )=\frac{\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } f(t) e^{i t \omega } \, dt}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}$